# ASP.NET - Use codebehind for a menu click event C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a logout menu using css in my project. Usually css menu only accepts link via

```
<a href="some page here"></a>
```

Now, what I want is the Logout menu will call function from codebehind.
My code for logout button:

```
<li><div class="some css class here"><a>Logout</a></div></li>
```

and the function I want to call:

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
```

Any possible solutions for calling btnLogout_Click on my Logout menu? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why not make a button...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using anchor use `LinkButton`

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Logout" 
           OnClick="atag_ServerClick" 
           runat="server"/>
```

and get your code work :)

In short just replace `<a>Logout</a>` with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<li><div class="some css class here"><a id="atag" onserverclick="atag_ServerClick" runat="server">Logout</a></div></li>
```

In codebehind you have to call the anchor tag's function:

```
private void atag_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
       atag.Target="url";
}
```

**OR**

As per your Requirement:

```
  private void atag_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
    }
```

Hope this helps...